# Is it possible to make a customized template of config/application.rb in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Provided that each time I generate a new Rails Application I have to edit config/application.rb to set always the same config settings, like "default locale". I wish to know if it is possible to make a template of application.rb? With the purpose of including all my frequent settings and then have them automatically included in new Apps. For example, when I run: `rails new website -m template.rb`

PD: Default application.rb generator is located in `railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/application.rb`

Comment: Why can't you just copy/paste it?

Comment: To prevent repeating actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thor actions to inject your lines to `application.rb` inside your `template.rb`. For example:

```
insertion_text = <<-TEXT
  \n
  config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
TEXT

inject_into_file "config/application.rb", insertion_text, :after => "# config.i18n.default_locale = :de"
```